# TeXstudio log file in different language cannot be parsed for error information

Tags: texstudio

I recently updated my copy of TeXstudio, and find I my log files are now written in another (Asian?) language. They cannot be parsed by TeXstudio, and so give essentially no debugging information. Strange and frustrating.

This happens with multiple LaTeX projects. Here is a screenshot. Any ideas short of clean install?

[image: example image showing log rendering]

Comment: what does the actual `.log` file look like if you look at it in another editor (I assume it doesn't look like that?)

Comment: which version of TeXstudio are you currently using and on what system?

Comment: setup: TeXstudio 2.11.2, Windows 10, MiKTeX.   `.log` file looks normal in notepad++.   And I ended up clean installing to fix this (including discarding my saved profile data). ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: This is quite likely an encoding issue. Note that the characters in the screenshot are not from the same language, but from many different scripts. (The reason you see so many CJK characters is that a large fraction of the Unicode range is covered by them.) So whatever wrote the file wrote it in some other encoding, while whatever is reading the file (in the screenshot above) is interpreting it as Unicode (probably UTF-8).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clean install fixed this ¯_(ツ)_/¯